# Significance Testing in R

Tags: r, rstudio, ab-testing, significance, t-test

I am trying to determine whether there is a significant difference between two interfaces. I have a text file that looks like this:

```
group   conversion
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   0
A   1
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   1
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   1
A   0
A   0
A   1
A   1
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   0
B   1
B   0
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
B   1
```

Now I need to find out which method I should use while doing this. So far I've tried the Welch's Two Sample T-test method, which I think is correct. But is that the correct way of determining whether there is a significance or not? **By the way, the significance level is 5%.**

This is my code:

```
# Load in the values from "test.txt"
dat = read.delim(“test.txt”)

# Calculate the amount of unique values
length(unique(dat$group))

# Calculate the p-value
t.test(dat$conversion ~ dat$group)
```

The output on the p-value was: **0.2586**, which is larger than **0.05**, which should mean there is no significance, right? Or am I doing something wrong? I'm a beginner at R.

Comment: You have a binary outcome variable so this method is not useful, consider running a binomial test. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133392/how-can-i-run-a-t-test-in-this-situation-of-two-processes-having-binary-outcomes

Comment: You say it's not useful, but is it still correct? I mean, it may not be the best method of doing it but would my method work? Or is it incorrect? @timfaber

Comment: I would say it is incorrect because it would be produce unreliable test results. This is explained in more detail in the link

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for the Fisher's T-test

using your data I created a data frame named `x`:

```
head(x)
  group conversion
1     A          0
2     A          0
3     A          1
4     A          0
5     A          0
6     A          1
```

then I made a frequency table:

```
y<-table(x)  

# and previewed the count table:
y
     conversion
group  0  1
    A 50 50
    B 58 42
```

Then you run a Fisher's t-test:

```
fisher.test(y)  

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  y

p-value = 0.3207

alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3989079 1.3135633

sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.7253254
```

And it even tells you that it is for comparing counts. It is a way of evaluating exactly the difference between two categorical identities.